# Collatz Equation = Automate the Boring Stuff - Chapter 3

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Collatz program from the project found at the end of chapter 3 of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python.  Following is the project description:

Write a function named collatz() that has one parameter named number. If the number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value. If the number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1. Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps calling collatz() on that number until the function returns the value 1.

The output of this program could look something like this:

Enter number: 3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

Question: Why am i stuck with in an infinite loop when I enter an integer? I can't seem to get out of this no matter how many times I read about a while loop. Could someone please explain how can i get the program to run the collatz function again and again using the result when the collatz function is run for the first time?

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number//2)
        return number//2

    elif number % 2 != 0:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        return 3 * number + 1

while True:
    print('Enter integer: ')
    digit = int(input())
    while digit > 1:
        collatz(digit)
        if collatz(digit) == 1:
            print('This is the end of the collatz test.')
            break
    if digit < 0:
        print('This is an error. Please try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `collatz()` function returns a new number, but within your while loop, you aren't doing anything with the number it returns. This means that the number returned by `collatz()` is immediately thrown away, and the value of `digit` never changes after the user enters it.

```
while True:
    print('Enter integer: ')
    digit = int(input())
    while digit > 1:  # Nothing inside the loop changes this value
        collatz(digit)  # This function's return value is ignored
        if collatz(digit) == 1:
            print('This is the end of the collatz test.')
            break
```

The loop will work if you update the value of `digit` each time, until that value eventually equals 1:

```
while True:
    print('Enter integer: ')
    digit = int(input())
    while digit > 1:
        digit = collatz(digit)  # Digit is now different each iteration
        if digit == 1:  # No need to call the function a second time
            print('This is the end of the collatz test.')
            break
```